# SQL Server Stored Procedure - not returning expected data

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that doesn't return the record i want and that record exists:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Student_SearchByName]
@FName NVarchar
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
       StudentID, FName, LName, Student.BirthDate, 
       DATEDIFF(hour, BirthDate, GETDATE()) / 8766 As 'Age' 
   FROM
       Student 
   WHERE 
       Student.FName = @FName
END
```

I fill the parameter in Visual Studio and also tried:

```
SELECT 
    StudentID, FName, LName, Student.BirthDate,
    DATEDIFF(hour, BirthDate, GETDATE()) / 8766 As 'Age' 
FROM
    Student 
WHERE
    Student.FName = 'Name'
```

and it worked, but when I use the parameter I get no result!

Answer (score 2):

If you specify this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Student_SearchByName]
    @FName NVarchar
```

then your `@FName` is **exactly ONE character** long - you porbably don't want that.

You should **always** specify an explicit **length** for any `(N)VARCHAR` variables and parameters!

Use something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Student_SearchByName]
   @FName NVarchar(100)
```

or whatever makes sense for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the length of the NVarchar, otherwise SQL Server truncates to the first char.
So it become:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Student_SearchByName]
// Student.FName always less than 500 characters
@FName NVarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT StudentID,FName,LName,Student.BirthDate,DATEDIFF(hour,BirthDate,GETDATE())/8766      As 'Age' 
    from Student where Student.FName=@FName
END
```